# Numerical Integration of functions involving PolyLog

Tags: numerical-integration

How to find the accurate numerical integration of highly oscillating functions involving ploylogs for example;

```
NIntegrate[
 PolyLog[2, E^(-2 I \[Pi] x)] PolyLog[2, 
   E^(-2 I \[Pi] Sqrt[321 + 712 x + 4 x^2])], {x, 1, 10^25}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 500]
```

The default global adaptive method above is currently not converging, is there any other integration strategy that coulf work for such functions.

Comment: Are you really trying to integrate to 10^25? Or are you really trying to integrate to infinity?  If so, do you know that the integral should actually converge?

Comment: I'm trying to integrate to 10^25